# Show that $g \in L^2 ([1, \infty))$, given the following.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(1) = 0$, $f' (x)$ is continuous and bounded, and $f' \in L^2 ([1, \infty))$.

Define $g(x) := \frac{f(x)}{x}$. Show $g \in L^2 ([1 , \infty))$.

My thoughts: the standard idea is to write $f(x) = \int_1^x f' (x) dx$. H\"older's yields 
$$|f(x)| \leq (x-1)^{1/2} ||f'||_2$$
Whence
$$||g||_2 \leq \Big( \int_1^\infty \frac{x-1}{x^2} dx \Big) ||f'||_2^2$$
My issue is that the right hand side is clearly infinite, and I am unsure of how to fix this. I really haven't employed continuity of $f$ nor boundedness of $f'$; maybe it would be more convenient to note
$$|f(x)| \leq (x-1) ||f'||_\infty$$
But this seems to be a weaker inequality. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\int_{1}^{x}f'(t)\,dt $$
leads to $|f(x)|\leq M(x-1)$ by the boundedness of $f'$ and to $|f(x)|\leq K\sqrt{x-1}$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Then
$$ \int_{1}^{T}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\underbrace{\left[-\frac{f(x)^2}{x}\right]_{1}^{T}}_{\text{negative and bounded}}+\int_{1}^{T}\frac{2\,f(x)\,f'(x)}{x}\,dx$$
leads to
$$\int_{1}^{T}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx\leq 2K\sqrt{\int_{1}^{T}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx} $$
then to $\int_{1}^{T}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx \leq 4K^2 $ for any $T$ large enough.
This inequality is sharp: it is enough to consider the case $f'(t)=\frac{1}{t^{1/2+\varepsilon}}$ as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$.

Comment: How does one forget integration by parts... Thank you.

Comment: @Rellek: I fixed a few typos. Luckily the proof simplified, rather than becoming more involved.

Comment: Why does this show that $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx$ is bounded? The equation 
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx\leq 2K\sqrt{\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx}$$
could just as well be $+\infty \le 2K \sqrt{+\infty}$.

Comment: No, that cannot be the case. He gets the final inequality for arbitrary $T$, and we can assume WLOG that $\int_1^T f^2/x^2$ is not identically $0$. Then, we are allowed to divide over. Since $T$ is arbitrary, taking the limit as $T \to \infty$ gives that the norm is bounded above by $2K$.